# windows command line utility to download from both http:// and file:// with progress

Tags: command-line, batch, wget, curl

is there a windows command line utility that supports downloading from both `http://` and `file://` with `progress`?

already tried:

- `powershell Invoke-WebRequest` : not working on windows 7
- `powershell (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile()` : does not report progress
- `bitsadmin` : slow and shows "deprecated" on windows 7 and does not output progress to stdout

usage:

```
powershell -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://server/test.txt', 'D:\test.txt')"
powershell -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('file://server/test.txt', 'D:\test.txt')"
powershell -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('file:///C:/test.txt', 'D:\test.txt')"

powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest 'http://server/test.txt' -UseBasicParsing -OutFile 'D:\test.txt'"
powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest 'file://server/test.txt' -UseBasicParsing -OutFile 'D:\test.txt'"
powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest 'file:///C:/test.txt' -UseBasicParsing -OutFile 'D:\test.txt'"

bitsadmin /transfer Job1 /download /priority normal "http://server/test.txt" "D:\test.txt"
bitsadmin /transfer Job1 /download /priority normal "file://server/test.txt" "D:\test.txt"
bitsadmin /transfer Job1 /download /priority normal "file:///C:/test.txt" "D:\test.txt"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're okay with two applications, `copy /z` will give you a percentage complete for local files:

[image]

For http(s), `wget` is [available for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm):

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why he was using file:// for a local copy. ?

Comment: I'm not sure either, perhaps he's hoping there's a wget that can handle that protocol for ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with making this small .net console app

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length < 2)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("invalid arguments!");
        return -1;
    }

    try
    {
        var source = args[0];
        var destination = args[1];

        var webClient = new WebClient();

        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("{0} of {1} bytes, {2}% downloaded...", e.BytesReceived, e.TotalBytesToReceive, e.ProgressPercentage);
        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("Download completed: {0} to {1}", source, destination);

        Console.WriteLine("Download started: {0} to {1}", source, destination);
        webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(source), destination).Wait();
        return 0;
    }
    catch(Exception x)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine(x.Message);
        return -2;
    }
}
```